# Calibrating Accelerometer Sensor

Tags: sensors

I'm working with an Adafruit LSM303DLHC Accelerometer Sensor hooked up to an Arduino.  I've downloaded the appropriate libraries to make it work and uploaded the example sketch "accelsensor.pde".  I then placed my sensor at rest on a flat surface and obtained the following acceleration vector values on average, in units of meters per second:

```
X: -0.24  Y: -0.71  Z: 10.47
```

At rest, each of these three values fluctuate approximately +-0.04 on average.

As I see it, the values are off a bit.  At rest, the X and Y components should hover closer to 0m/s^2 while the Z component should be closer to 9.8m/s^2.

What is the best way to compensate for this biased measurement?  Should I simply add back the average observed bias?  Or is there a more robust method to calibrate the sensor values?

Answer (score 1):

there are varius calculation.

At the end of the day, if take a point in every position (under no acceleration), you should end up with a sphere, or matematically speacking, wthe lenght of the vector should be equal to gravity, so `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z) = G` or, to do less computing `x*x+y*y+z*z = G*G` (same apply for magnetometer, but using local magnetic force, or gyroscope, using a know-speed rotation like a LP player)

To create that spere you have to take many point, and find a multiplicator (or function) for each axes. That is particualary important when one axes has differnet precision of others, you are `linearizing` the axis output, and then `normalizig` its value relative to others axes.

Once you have corrected the vector lenght to have a spere, you should look at the offset of the sphere; if its `center` point is not on the `origin` point 0,0,0 then the differece between `center` and `origin` is the correction you talk about. This is offset correction.

Also many (well, all) sensor are affected on their temperature; many claim to be "thermocompensated", that means this difference is less evident due to some some sort of hardware and/or software filtering.

Comment: What do you mean by "take a point in every position"?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the fluctuation, you could always try a moving average. It isn't hard to modify the `Smoothing` example (under `File->Examples->1. Analog->Smoothing`) to accept accelerometer values.

As for the slight offset in the X & Y values, that is probably because your sensor isn't sitting perfectly flat.

Comment: Am i correct to assume that the z-axis should (ideally) give an acceleration value of approximately 9.8m/s^2? Or should it really read 0m/s^2 at rest?

Comment: @Paul - yes you are correct